# Makefile does not "see" %.o %.asm rule

Tags: makefile, nasm

I'm writing a project and wanted to make one, good makefile. At some point I noticed that it doesn't work for multiple .asm files, I did some research and modified my file, so it looks like this:

```
PROJDIRS := kernel lib
ASMFILES := $(shell find $(PROJDIRS) -type f -name "*.asm")
SRCFILES := $(shell find $(PROJDIRS) -type f -name "*.c")
HDRFILES := $(shell find $(PROJDIRS) -type f -name "*.h")

ASMOBJCT := $(patsubst %.asm,%.o,$(ASMFILES))
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCFILES))
TSTFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%_t,$(SRCFILES))

DEPFILES    := $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRCFILES))
TSTDEPFILES := $(patsubst %,%.d,$(TSTFILES))

WARNINGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

NASM=nasm
CC=/usr/local/cross/bin/i686-elf-gcc
CFLAGS=-nostdlib -nostdinc -ffreestanding -O2 $(WARNINGS) -masm=intel -Iinclude -std=c99
LDFLAGS=-T link.ld -nostdlib -ffreestanding -O2 -lgcc
ASFLAGS=-felf

all: $(OBJFILES) link

clean:
    -rm kernel/*.o
    -rm kernel/hal/*.o
    -rm _bin_/*.elf

link:
    /usr/local/cross/bin/i686-elf-gcc $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJFILES) $(ASMOBJCT) -o _bin_/kernel.elf

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

%.o: %.asm
    $(NASM) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

But for some reason the last one does not execute, as a result linker throws an error that required object files are not found. I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Do you have any idea how do I fix this weird issue?

Comment: Are the `TSTFILES` supposed to be `%_t` or should that be `%.t`? This isn't related to your problem at all I just noticed the mismatch and figured I'd check.

Comment: Oh, it should be %.t. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never tell make to build them.

Your default rule is `all: $(OBJFILES) link` which tells to build everything in `$(OBJFILES)` and the `link` target. This doesn't include anything in `$(ASMOBJCT)` so when `link` goes to use them they don't exist.

You can fix this by putting the actual prereqs for the `link` target on the `link:` line like so:

```
link: $(OBJFILES) $(ASMOBJCT)
```

and then use `$^` (all prereqs) instead of `$(OBJFILES) $(ASMOBJCT)` on the linking line.

You could then drop `$(OBJFILES)` from the `all` target prereq list since you won't need it there anymore.

You could also replace `link` with `_bin_/kernel.elf` on the `all` target line and then in the `link:` target line and then use `-o '$@'` (rule target) on the linking line instead of writing it out.