# Why is Makefile ignoring my rule for .o files?

Tags: makefile

*(Note: this appears related to [Makefile does not "see" %.o %.asm rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435416/makefile-does-not-see-o-asm-rule), yet different...)*

#### Short form:

Why is Makefile ignoring my rule for `%.o` files?

#### Details:

My Makefile includes the following rule:

```
%.o : %.c %.h $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c $(<) -o $@
```

From this, I *expect* to see this (for a typical file):

```
 gcc -O0 -Wall -g -DMU_LOG_ENABLED -I../ports/posix -c time_test.c -o time_test.o
```

but instead my Makefile is generating this (note the missing -I and different order of -c and -o):

```
gcc -O0 -Wall -g -DMU_LOG_ENABLED   -c -o time_test.o time_test.c
```

My guess is that Make is using a built-in rule rather than the one I gave it, but I can't fathom why.  What must I do to make Make honor my `%.o` rule?

#### More Details:

Here's the entirety of the Makefile:

```
EXCLUDES := _template_test.c

# In this src directory, all .c files are compiled into .o files
SOURCES := $(filter-out $(EXCLUDES), $(wildcard *.c))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))
HEADERS := $(patsubst %.c,%.h,$(SOURCES))

# .h files that are not associated with a .c file, but should be copied to the
# .../include release directory.  Note that touching any of these files will
# cause a recompilation of the SOURCES.
INCLUDES :=

CC     = gcc

# Good settings for debugging
CFLAGS  = -O0 -Wall -g -DMU_LOG_ENABLED

IFLAGS = -I../ports/posix

%.o : %.c %.h $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c $(<) -o $@

objects: $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)
```

#### Addendum:

At the suggestion of [G.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371123/g-m), I tried with the `--no-builtin-rules` option:

```
$ make --no-builtin-rules objects
make: *** No rule to make target `time_test.o', needed by `objects'. Stop.
```

... which strengthens [Mad Scientist's hypothesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58419017/558639) that the rule I gave isn't being applied.

Comment: What happens if you invoke make with the `--no-builtin-rules` option (just by way of a check)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a rule like this:

```
%.o : %.c %.h $(INCLUDES)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c $(<) -o $@
```

this rule will only be applied if make can either find, or build, all the prerequisites of the target.

So, if you want to build `foo.o`, then make must be able to find or build the files `foo.c`, `foo.h`, and the expansion of `$(INCLUDES)` (which in your example above appears to be empty.

So, in your example above, it most likely means that you don't have a `time_test.h` file in your directory.

You can use `make -d` (redirect voluminous output!) to see why make decided not to use that pattern rule.

Comment: Ding ding ding!  That's exactly it.  My unit test sources don't have .h files, only the unit testing support files.  Good to know, thank you.

Comment: ...Changing `HEADERS := $(patsubst %.c,%.h,$(SOURCES))` to `HEADERS := $(wildcard *.h)` did the trick. (Silly 5 minute editing limit!:)